# Why is my cpp unit test looking for an extra library at runtime?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans-8

Help!  I am trying to run a cpp unit test in Netbeans 8.2.  The main code library and the unit tests all compile just fine, but when I try to run the unit test, I get this error message

```
error while loading shared libraries: --library=cppunit: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am currently using the library flags "-Wl, -soname, -lcppunit, -ldl" in the "Properties -> Build -> Linker -> Additional Options" in the project Properties section.  When I use the command "-ldd ./filename" on the executable from the linux command line, the results are:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc34ac000)
libSpaceTime.so => /mnt/d/code/lib/libSpaceTime.so (0x00007f38a7060000)
--library=cppunit => not found
libcppunit-1.13.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit-1.13.so.0 (0x00007f38a6e00000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f38a6a70000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f38a6760000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f38a6530000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f38a6160000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f38a5f50000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f38a7400000)
```

THis problem only cropped up recently; prior to now, the compiler never looked for this --library=cppunit option, and I have previously compiled and run these unit tests with no problems.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: So what kind of result are you expecting when using `-lcppunit`?

Comment: I expect --library=cppunit to not show up at all.  You can see that the code is linking up to libcppunit-1.13.so.0, and when this code has compiled and run in the past I've never seen it request --library=cppunit before.  I've never seen --library=cppunit show up as a requested library in a executable before - I would expect libcppunit-1.13.so.0 to take care of it.

Comment: Oh God, my question was so hard it stumped StackOverflow.  Now I really have no clue what to do.

Comment: It is more like this question lacks necessary details. It does not even have build log or any details that would help to figure out where does `--library=cppunit` come from.

Comment: I’m sorry, I didn’t know I hadn’t included all necessary details.  My internet is screwy right now, but I will upload the data when I can.  Can you please tell me what else you would need to see to diagnose the problem so I don’t waste anyone’s time with unnecessary back-and-forth?

Comment: I’ll add that part of the reason I’m so stumped is that I didn’t change any configuration data for the project or request any new libraries.  It’s never needed this—library-cppunit before, and with the — prefix I’m not sure that —library-cppunit is even a real library at all.